# Error from openNLP under R

Tags: r, text-mining, opennlp

```
library(openNLP)
library(openNLPmodels.es)
sentence="Por lo menos los paquetes modelo de idioma en Inglés y en español, previamente"
tagPOS(sentence, language = "es")
Error in .jcall(tagger, "S", "tag", x) : 
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

For english sentences everything works well.
What does that error mean and how could I ride of it ?

the same error for single word :

```
tagPOS("menos", language = "openNLPmodels.se")
    Error in .jcall(tagger, "S", "tag", x) : 
      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```